# Can't lazy load my related data in MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been playing around with the entity framework in MVC, but I seem to have run into a problem regarding 'lazy loading'. I have a simple web application that scrapes data from a well known movie database, and allows the user to save this data into a database. I have a Film class which contains details like title, release date, director.... etc. I also have a Genre class, and I have a icollection of genre inside the Film class.

The problem I am having is that I can't seem to load the genre information when I want to pass  an IEnumerable query to a view.

Here is Film class:

```
 public class Film
{
    [Key]
    public int FilmId { get; set; }
    public string FilmTitle { get; set; }
    public int FilmReleaseYear { get; set; }
    public string FilmDirector { get; set; }
    public string FilmRating { get; set; }
    public string FilmImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string FilmImdbUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Genre> FilmGenres { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FilmCastMember> FilmCastList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FilmReview> FilmReviews { get; set; }

    public Film()
    {
        FilmGenres = new List<Genre>();
        FilmCastList = new List<FilmCastMember>();
        FilmReviews = new List<FilmReview>();
    }
}
```

Here is my Genre class:

```
public class Genre
{   
    [Key]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string GenreType { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my action method

```
public ActionResult MyFilms()
    {
        IEnumerable<Film> films = from film in db.Films.Include("Genres")
                                  select film;

        return View(films);
    }
```

The problem I have is that when i'm in the view for this method, I try to access the GenreType of a film using a foreach loop, however, it doesn't give me that option. All the data is linked inside my database, so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Any help would be great.

New action method:

```
public ActionResult MyFilms()
    {
        IEnumerable<Film> films = from film in db.Films.Include("FilmReviews").Include("FilmGenres").Include("FilmCastList")
                                  select film;

        return View(films);
    }
```

New View for that method:

```
 @model IEnumerable<MvcFilmFinder.Models.Film>

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "MyFilms";
  }

  @foreach (var film in Model)
  {
      <h2>@film.FilmTitle</h2>
      <img src="@film.FilmImageUrl" alt="@film.FilmTitle" />

      foreach (var genre in film.FilmGenres)
      {
         <p>@genre.GenreType</p>
      }

      foreach (var genre in film.FilmGenres)
      {
         <p>@genre.GenreId</p>
      }

      foreach (var review in film.FilmReviews)
      {
         <p>@review.ReviewAuthor</p>
      }
  }
```

Comment: `Include("FilmGenres")`

Comment: Hi @NSGaga, unfortunately, that didn't work. I'm trying to achieve this:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4

If you navigate to the Updating Store Browse and Details to use live data section

Comment: @gb1986 - I think you mean eagerly loading above, not lazy loading. You know you're going to use `FilmGenres` so you _eagerly_ load them at the start and only have one trip to the database (as opposed to lazy loading where you don't use `Include` and another query would execute when you get to `film.FilmGenre`). Also, if you're using EF 4.1 or later you should be able to have your `Include` statements strongly typed like `.Include(f => f.FilmGenres)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Controller code to:

```
public ActionResult MyFilms()
{
    var films = from film in db.Films.Include("FilmGenres")
                select film;

    return View(films);
}
```

Your view should look like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<projectname.Models.Film>

@foreach (var film in Model)
{
    foreach (var genre in film)
    {
        // genre stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @MiniRagnarok, I've added that include to my controller action and it now works. I've also added the CastList and Reviews collection using the include method. I just want to know if this is the the best way to achieve this, as the chained includes seem a bit odd. I've added the new action method and view to the code at the top

Comment: @MiniRagnarok - you're passing `IEnumerable<Film>` to the `View` but the model you've defined for the `View` is simply `Film`. I think @gb1986's `View` is fine (if you disregard the two foreach loops both enumerating through `FilmGenres`) and their question is more regarding the `Include`.

Comment: @gb1986 You're right that this is odd but it's really up to you. In real life I tend to have simpler Models and Views but sometimes things get complicated.